# How can I get to Settings if there is no physical settings button?

Tags: settings, buttons, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I just got a Samsung S5 and it has a physical Back, Home and Task Manager button. No settings button ... some apps I use do not have a settings button (I guess it sees the physical buttons and assumes settings is one of them).
Is there any way to accessing app settings? Maybe a gesture I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think, apps depending on button type (physical or virtaul) change their UI.

Comment: Are you talking about a *menu* button? It's usually labelled with three dots (or two or four horizontal lines) and brings up a pop-up menu of actions? I only ask to make it easier for other visitors to find your question.

Comment: A little bit of search reveals this button is the "Action Overflow" button. Generally three dots, or three dash... sometimes referred too as the Hamburger Button. And @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan apps *totally* change which buttons they display depending on which physical buttons exist... some better than others though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hold down the Task Manager button and it will show the application menu.

Comment: In case of Samsung XCover 3 (Android 6.0) I had to press and hold the Back button to trigger settings.